# Error while creating a new project using Scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy

I installed Scrapy on Fedora 20 and when I tried to create a new project it gives me the following error:

```
/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Twisted-14.0.0-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/twisted/internet/_sslverify.py:184: UserWarning: You do not have the service_identity module installed. Please install it from <https://pypi.python.org/pypi/service_identity>. Without the service_identity module and a recent enough pyOpenSSL tosupport it, Twisted can perform only rudimentary TLS client hostnameverification.  Many valid certificate/hostname mappings may be rejected.
```

I tried searching for the module `service_identity` but in vain!
Could anyone help me in this regard.

Thanks in advance

Comment: This warning (not an error) should not prevent Scrapy from running OK when SSL is not  necessary

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `pip install service_identity` to resolve this issue.

Comment: how can I get rid of the warning without installing this module?